# Set a Vector input as a variable in QGIS Tool Script

Tags: pyqgis

In a QGIS script, how do you set a Vector input (via your tool's GUI) as a variable which can then be used in subsequent processing in your tool's script?

I know how to set a map Layer as a variable, for example:

```
 pts = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('civic_pts')[0]
```

But instead of hard-wiring my file inputs like that, I want the flexibility of setting my inputs via the tool's GUI.

I've tried:

```
 ##Input_civic_pts=vector
```

...and then tried using it later in the script, for example...

```
 for feat in Input_civic_pts.getFeatures():
```

...but this generates an error.

The same script works fine when I hard-wire the civic_pts file as above.

Obviously I don't know how to convert an Input to a scripting variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

`##Input_civic_pts=vector`

doesn't mean the layer object, you have to use a function to get the layer object itself:

`inputLayer = processing.getObject(Input_civic_pts)`

See the documentation here: http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/ca/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html